# IIS restarts W3Svc when Creating new Virtual Directory from Default Web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

Any ideas why MS in their infinite wisdom makes IIS 6 restart the W3C Service when I create an application/or virtual directory and then change the runtime version?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You know you can upvote a correct answer as well as marking correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is any change in the web.config or in virutal directory, application will be restarted and hence created sessions also expired
[Seven reason for application restart in Aspnet](http://janakiramaraobatchu.blogspot.fr/2007/08/seven-reason-for-application-restart-in.html)

best practice would be any change like you are doing, to down to application server by putting App_Offline.htm on root.